# jQuery not functioning right after publish to test server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, telerik-grid

I have the following jQuery in  a user control using a Telerik RadGrid:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       
        var warnMessage = "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save and Continue button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select').change(function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                    if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage;
                }
            });
            $('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select').on('DOMNodeRemoved', function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                    if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage;
                }
            });
            $('input:submit').click(function (e) {
                warnMessage = null;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What it's meant to do is to keep a user from clicking away from the page using several of these controls without saving their changes. When I run this in VS2013, it works fine, triggering the pop-up when anything is added/updated/deleted in the RadGrid and the user attempts to leave the page without saving. However after publishing to the test server,the .click is never hit, so when a user tries to add another entry to the grid, the warning message fires again, and the on DOMNodeRemoved never works. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the code? Or is there something wrong with the server? I'm new to jQuery, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I will post more info if needed.

Comment: you need to give some working chunk of code that could be put on server and checked... noone will answer for this in this state...

Comment: Is your testing server using the https protocol? If so you should change your url to `//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js`

Comment: Have you checked browser console for any errors?

Comment: Also if you are using Telerik, Script code must be inside RadCodeBlock if you use any server control in script.

Comment: @Hemal Looked back into the console and found there was an object doesn't support property or method 'addeventlistener' error occurring.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the console fo rthe test-server site, I found I was getting an "object doesn't support property or method 'addeventlistener'" error. I went to the Master page of the site and added a meta to check for the compatibility mode and that fixed it right up.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/modernizr.js"></script></head>
```

**UPDATE**
After looking into this issue more, it's not that JQuery wasn't working per se, it was that the functionality did not exist for my solution to work in IE9.

Comment: Just as a heads up, for whatever reason the above code only works for IE 11 and up, IE9 seems to ignore this completely.